# Базы данных

Tags: база-данных, книги

Здравствуйте. В университете будем проходить такой предмет как "Базы данных" и хочется узнать:

а) какую литературу почитать по данной теме, хочу уже придти с каким то багажом, ну и для себя.... надеяться на то, что мне все там разжуют полный бред, т.к. все знают какое у нас высшее образование по IT направлению.

б) что вообще будет включать данный курс,  я понимаю, что программы могут отличаться, но в общих чертах, я думаю, все же можно объяснить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первые несколько занятий Вы, скорее всего, будете изучать общую теорию БД: архитектуры БД по модели данных (иерархическая, сетевая, реляционная), архитектуры БД по виду реализации (локальная, файл-серверная, клиент-серверные: "толстый" ("сильный") клиент, "тонкий" ("слабый") клиент), нормализацию БД и нормальные формы, ещё, возможно, услышите пару слов про ER-диаграммы. Возможно, Вам скажут в двух словах о механизмах доступа к данным (это зависит от среды программирования, которая изучается в Вашем университете, если это Delphi или C++ Builder, то: BDE, ADO (dbGo), dbExpress), хотя, это вряд-ли. Ну, конечно же, основы языка SQL - в БД без него никак. А, вот, насчёт литературы, я думаю, лучше с преподавателем посоветоваться, т. к. это зависит от того какую именно среду для разработки БД Вы будете использовать, как правило, во многих книгах, посвящённых БД, сначала идёт общая теория. Можете взять что-нибудь по языку SQL для начинающих или книгу по общей теории БД - не ошибётесь. Или, как вариант, пройдите какой-нибудь курс на ИНТУИТЕ: http://www.intuit.ru/. Только перед прохождением бывает очень полезно почитать отзывы, а-то там иногда попадаются очень сложные курсы (один такой есть и по БД).